# MySQL convert double to varchar only if null

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm trying to get a `DOUBLE` type value out of my database for use in a report. If this value is `NULL`, then the report should state `"N/A"`.

I'm just having some difficulty with the sql to make this work:

```
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(billablerate, 'N/A'), CHAR(5)) AS billablerate FROM rates
```

Something tells me that these functions can't be combined like this, but I don't know how else to get them both in.

Any assistance would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(CAST(billablerate AS char (5)), 'N/A') AS billablerate FROM rates
```

works for:

```
SELECT IFNULL(CAST(null AS char (5)), 'N/A') AS exp; // N/A
SELECT IFNULL(CAST(10 AS char (5)), 'N/A') AS exp; // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its the order of the functions thats causing you trouble.

Try:

```
SELECT IF(billablerate IS NULL, 'N/A', CONVERT(billablerate, CHAR(5))) as billablerate FROM rates
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error in my command was syntactical, see below:

My original code:

```
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(billablerate, 'N/A'), CHAR(5)) AS billablerate FROM rates
```

The fix:

```
SELECT CAST(IFNULL(billablerate, 'N/A') AS CHAR(5)) AS billablerate FROM rates
```